# jQuery/Bootstrap popover hide clicking on outside of content placeholder div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am new jQuery and boostrap. Using boostrap popover I have implemented multiple popover for a single page. My popover html and js script as followings:

```
  <a  data-toggle="popover" class="btn popper btn-default ">                                           
                                    Click me 1                                           
   </a> 
   <div class="popper-content hide profile-popover">
       This content place for click me 1 button
    </div>

     <a  data-toggle="popover" class="btn popper btn-default ">                                           
         Click me 2                                           
       </a> 
   <div class="popper-content hide profile-popover">
         This content place for click me 2 button
     </div>
```

js scripts for that :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.popper').popover({
  placement: 'bottom',
container: 'body',
html: true,
content: function () {
    return $(this).next('.popper-content').html();
  }
 });
 });
</script>
```

Pop over works fine but now I am trying implement a scripts that will hide all open popover throughout my page if anyone clicked outside of the popover content.

Here is the my full code snippet please check and let me know how can I hide all open popover if clicked on outside of content places.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.popper').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $(this).next('.popper-content').html();
    }
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Popover</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover </h3>
                                 <a  data-toggle="popover" class="btn popper btn-default ">                                           
                                        Click me 1
                                           
                                 </a> 
                                   <div class="popper-content hide profile-popover">
                                             This content place for click me 1 button
                                    </div>

                                       <a  data-toggle="popover" class="btn popper btn-default ">                                           
                                        Click me 2
                                           
                                        </a> 
                                    <div class="popper-content hide profile-popover">
                                             This content place for click me 2 button
                                    </div>
 
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply add following codes inside of your document **$(document).ready** function hopefully your aspect will be resolved:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  if(!($(e.target).hasClass("popover-content"))){
    $(".popover").popover('hide');
    }
});
```

I have attached jQuery and html code snippet as following:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.popper').popover({
      placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $(this).next('.popper-content').html();
      }
     });


    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
          if(!($(e.target).hasClass("popover-content"))){
         $(".popover").popover('hide');
      }
     });




     });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Popover</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3 class="popper-content dd">Popover </h3>
                                 <a  data-toggle="popover" class="btn popper btn-default ">                                           
                                        Click me 1
                                           
                                 </a> 
                                   <div class="popper-content hide profile-popover">
                                             This content place for click me 1 button
                                    </div>

                                       <a  data-toggle="popover" class="btn popper btn-default ">                                           
                                        Click me 2
                                           
                                        </a> 
                                    <div class="popper-content hide profile-popover">
                                             This content place for click me 2 button
                                    </div>
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Run and check whether your issue resolves.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure all of your pop-overs have an extra class name that you can target all of them at the same time. Then you can use this code to loop through and hide them all.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
   var container = $('.popper-content');
   container.each(function() {
     if (container.is(e.target) || container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(this).popover('hide');
     }
    });
 });
```

Unless the click is inside the container then the pop-up will be hidden.